# Converting generator from read_sql in pandas to dataframe has failed

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read data from my oracle, I use the pandas's `read_sql` and set the parameter `chunksize=20000`,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine("my oracle")
df = pd.read_sql("select clause",engine,chunksize=20000)
```

It returns a iterator, and I want to convert this generator to a dataframe using`df = pd.DataFrame(df)`, but it's wrong, How can the iterator be converted to a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This iterator can be concatenated, then it return a dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat(df)
```

You can view [pandas.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) document.

If you can't use `concat` directly, try the following:

```
gens = pd.read_sql("select clause",engine,chunksize=20000)
dflist = []
for gen in gens:
    dflist.append(gen)
df = pd.concat(dflist)
```

Comment: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'generator'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: @littlely  What is your version? There is no problem on me.

Comment: pandas 0.23 and python 3.6.5

Comment: @littlely  Try what I add.